# Conflicting Errors in Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a function "PrintHeader" for my project, defined in io.cpp.  Even though io.h is included in my main file, I get the error

```
error C3861: 'PrintHeader': identifier not found.
```

When I copy the function for PrintHeader into my main file, I get the errors

```
error LNK2005: 'void _cdeci PrintHeader(void)" (?PrintHeader@@YAXXZ) already defined in io.obj.
```

and

```
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found.
```

I can understand the second error set, since I do have it defined twice, but I don't understand why it doesn't work when I just remove the duplicate definition.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Main file

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "io.h"

void PrintHeader()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Month\tPrincipal\t Interest\t  Balance" << endl;
    cout << "-----\t---------\t---------\t---------" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World\n";
    PrintHeader();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

io.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "io.h"

void PrintHeader (void)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Month\tPrincipal\t Interest\t  Balance" << endl;
    cout << "-----\t---------\t---------\t---------" << endl;
}
```

io.h

```
#ifndef __IO_H__
#define __IO_H__

#include <string>
using namespace std;

void PrintHeader (void);

#endif
```

Comment: `using namespace` in a header is a really bad coding style

Comment: The io files were given to me for a class assignment with specific instructions not to modify them.  But it's great to know that my instructors are apparently clueless.  -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely including the wrong file in main.cpp. You can make sure it is the right file by right clicking on the `include "io.h"` and choosing open file.

Comment: You're right - it looks like io.h is a default library.  Is there a way to specify which io.h to use, without changing the names?  For my assignment, I'm not allowed to modify the io.cpp or io.h files that I'm using.

Comment: You most likely have the io.h file in a different folder than main.cpp, which is why it picks the one from the standard library.

Comment: @ronag - io.h is not part of the standard C or C++ libraries. It may be that some compilers provide it as an extension.

Comment: @ronag - Yep!  They appeared together in VS, but when I looked in Explorer, they were in different directories.  Copying the io files to the main directory fixed the problem.  Thanks!